# Encountering an error while using a variable inside CTE in oracle

Tags: oracle, variables, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I want to write the below SQL query(used in sql server) in Oracle SQL developer :

```
DECLARE @myVAR int;
SET @myVAR = 11;
WITH myCTE
AS (SELECT * FROM abc WHERE HostCount = @myVAR)
SELECT * FROM myCTE
```

Comment: What isn't working exactly? What do you need to do with the cursor results?

Comment: I have this huge query where I need to check the weekday and pass the (sysdate + or - n) accordingly to the query. something like below,the variable start_date to be pased to CTE followed: 
declare 
v_today varchar2(15); 
start_date date; 
begin 
select to_char(sysdate,'d') INTO v_today FROM DUAL; 
IF (v_today = '7') THEN 
select sysdate -2 INTO start_date FROM DUAL; 
ELSIF (v_today = '1') THEN 
select sysdate -2 INTO start_date FROM DUAL; 
END IF; END; 
with cte1 as (), 
with cte2 as ( .... ....trunc(start_date) ) 
select col1,... from cte2;

Comment: I’m still not clear what you want to do with the cursor results. Is this a report, for example?

Comment: Yes William, it is a report that generates daily based on the given start date.

Comment: Does this article about writing reports in SQL Developer help? https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/04/oracle-sql-developers-best-kept-secret-reports/

Comment: Heathers, In this case you don't need local parameter declaration by using such a query `with cte1 as
 (),
with cte2 as
 (.. .. .. .. decode( to_char(sysdate, 'd'), '7', trunc(sysdate) - 2 , '1', trunc(sysdate) - 2, trunc(sysdate) ))
select col1,.. . from cte2;` through using `decode()` function (or maybe`case..when` statement). Indeed, it's in the scope of another new question. ( the last part `, trunc(sysdate)` for the decode func. is intentionally added to be the `else` case ).

Comment: Thank you Barbaros, decode() function worked for my query :)

Answer (score 1):

For your case:

- `DECLARE` and `INT` keywords might be replaced with `VAR` and `NUMBER`,
  respectively
- The variable `myVAR` is qualified by `:` instead of `@`, assignment operator(`:=`) is used instead of equality sign (`=`) and nested between `BEGIN` and `END` keywords.
- The statements on the command
  line should be ended by `;` and then `/` .

Code:

```
SQL> VAR myVAR NUMBER;
SQL> BEGIN :myVAR := 11; END; 
  2  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
myVAR
---------
11

SQL> WITH myCTE
  2  AS (SELECT * FROM abc WHERE HostCount = :myVAR)
  3  SELECT * FROM myCTE;
  4  /

ID    COL1   HOSTCOUNT
---- ------ ----------
..     ...          11
..     ...          11

myVAR
---------
11
```

Comment: This is giving me PL/SQL compilation error:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement.

Comment: I have this huge query where I need to check the weekday and pass the (sysdate + or - n) accordingly to the query.

something like below,the variable start_date to be pased to CTE followed:
declare 
  v_today varchar2(15);
  start_date date;
begin
  select to_char(sysdate,'d')
  INTO v_today
  FROM DUAL;
  IF (v_today = '7') THEN
  select sysdate -2
  INTO start_date
  FROM DUAL;
  ELSIF (v_today = '1') THEN
  select sysdate -2
  INTO start_date
  FROM DUAL;
  END IF;
END;
with cte1 as
(),
with cte2 as
(
....
....trunc(start_date)
)
select col1,... from cte2;

Comment: @Heathers I don’t see how you could get that error from the code shown, as there is no PL/SQL block containing a `select` statement. Which line gives the error?

Comment: Writing this in Oracle SQL developer and getting the below error :

Error starting at line : 2 in command -
BEGIN :myVAR := 1; END;
WITH myCTE
    AS (select * from APT_V_TEST_CASE where TEST_CASE_ID = :myVAR)
    SELECT * FROM myCTE;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action: